# Regex to pull id containing digits and letters, regardless of what comes first

Tags: regex

I am trying to consistently pull Instagram shortcodes from urls, that look like this `https://instagram.com/p/2x7ELzlTVB/`. I was originally just using this:

```
var myRegex = /https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/p\/([\w-]+)\/?/g;
```

That works fine except in situations where the url is http instead of https or the www is missing. So, I then tried this:

```
\d+\w+
```

This works fine for a url similar to :

```
https://instagram.com/p/2x7ELzlTVB/
```

But not for:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/AW67NChA8By/
```

For this, it omits the 'AW'. I presume this is because I am looking for digits first, but how do I specify that I need all numbers/letters, regardless of order, in an elegant way (my regexes can get crazy)?

Comment: Return back to your first statement, does this work you mean `https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?instagram.com\/p\/([\w-]+)\/?`?

Comment: @revo, that does seem to work. It looks like I can just replace my initial solution with this. Can you provide an answer that includes why this would would be a better solution over another answer, seen below?

Comment: The other answer doesn't follow right approach. They mixed up the mean of character classes badly.

Comment: OK thanks. Can you provide an answer so that I can accept and you get credit for it? Otherwise I can simply upvote your comment

Answer (score -1):

This regex will match one or more alphanumeric characters: `[A-Za-z0-9]+`.

You can modify your regex to be this:

```
var myRegex = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?instagram.com\/[A-Za-z0-9]+/g;
```

Where the `s` in `https` is optional, as is the `www.` before instagram.

Comment: `[www\.|]` should be `(www\.|)` or simply `(www\.)?` You're making the classic mistake of confusing `()` with `[]`.